# Pycharm doesn't activate virtualenv in terminal after conda

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, virtualenv, conda

I'm working in a scrapy project with pycharm on Windows. It always opened terminal in correct virtualenv without problems. But since I've executed a conda installation of a particular package, the venv doesn't load anymore on terminal by default, though is setted in project. How can I solve this?

From idea.log:

```
2018-03-12 10:13:42,647 [  82638]   WARN - .python.run.PyVirtualEnvReader - Couldn't read shell environment: rv:1 text:0 out:""C:\Users\proprietario\AppData\Local\Temp\..\python.exe"" non ʠriconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
```